# Mocking default=timezone.now for unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm trying to write unit tests for a django app that does a lot of datetime operations.  I have installed [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to monkey patch django's `timezone.now` for my tests.

While I am able to successfully mock `timezone.now` when it is called normally (actually calling `timezone.now()` in my code, I am not able to mock it for models that are created with a `DateTimeField` with `default=timezone.now`.

---

I have a `User` model that contains the following:

```
from django.utils import timezone
...
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.pop('modified', True):
        self.modified = timezone.now()
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

My unit test looks like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def test_created(self):
    dt = datetime(2010, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    with patch.object(timezone, 'now', return_value=dt):
        user = User.objects.create(username='test')
        self.assertEquals(user.modified, dt)
        self.assertEquals(user.timestamp, dt)
```

---

`assertEquals(user.modified, dt)` passes, but `assertEquals(user.timestamp, dt)` does not.

**How can I mock `timezone.now` so that even `default=timezone.now` in my models will create the mock time?**

---

**Edit**

I know that I could just change my unit test to pass a `timestamp` of my choice (probably generated by the mocked `timezone.now`)...  Curious if there is a way that avoids that though.

Comment: could you provide a full relevant listing for `User` model? It is very important to know at what point the binding for default value is taking place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself.  The problem is that models are loaded before mock has patched the timezone module, so at the time the expression `default=timezone.now` is evaluated, it sets the `default` kwarg to the real `timezone.now` function.

The solution is the following:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.now())
```

Comment: Hi, @Jordan, after changing this default value, and run the python manage.py makemigrations command, I got error like: "raise ValueError("Cannot serialize function: lambda")", my python is version 3.5.3, django is 1.10.5

Comment: Do not do that! django cannot serialize a lambda, it will end up with an exception during makemigrations. Instead, create a wrapper function in a utils package `def now(): return timezone.now()` and use it everywhere

Answer (score 17):

Here's a method you can use that doesn't require altering your non-test code.  Just patch the `default` attributes of the fields you want to affect.  For example--

```
field = User._meta.get_field('timestamp')
mock_now = lambda: datetime(2010, 1, 1)
with patch.object(field, 'default', new=mock_now):
    # Your code here
```

You can write helper functions to make this less verbose.  For example, the following code--

```
@contextmanager
def patch_field(cls, field_name, dt):
    field = cls._meta.get_field(field_name)
    mock_now = lambda: dt
    with patch.object(field, 'default', new=mock_now):
        yield
```

would let you write--

```
with patch_field(User, 'timestamp', dt):
    # Your code here
```

Similarly, you can write helper context managers to patch multiple fields at once.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the test doesn't fail if the `default` argument isn't provided to the field, so it passes when it ought to fail

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you have an example? Is there any reason you can't add additional assertions to your test to make sure a failure happens in the situation you're concerned about?

Comment: The example would be to remove the `default=timezone.now` from the declaration for the timezone field and check whether the test passes or not. My experience was that the test passed when I expected it to fail due to there being no default.

Comment: We want to test that the field is set to the current date when no value is provided. This requires a callable that returns the current date to be passed to the `default` argument, but by patching the `default` argument, we actually overwrite whatever was there, so we're not testing the code as it would be in production. By mocking default, we actually test whether django uses the default argument correctly! So, that makes the patching all rather redundant. In the end, I opted for checking default was set to `timezone.now`: `self.assertEqual(event_datetime_field.default, timezone.now)`

Comment: In that case, yes, you wouldn't want to use this approach. The purpose of this approach is to ensure that test objects created in your tests have known (e.g. hard-coded) datetime values instead of values that vary depending on the current real datetime. So it's not meant for testing the field itself but rather as a supportive technique to ensure that tests using these objects are deterministic / reproducible.

Comment: Thank you!!! I just had to mock `get_default` instead of `default`.

Answer (score 6):

There is another easy way to do the above thing.

```
import myapp.models.timezone
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('django.utils.timezone.now')
def test_created(self, mock_timezone):
    dt = datetime(2010, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    mock_timezone.return_value = dt
    user = User.objects.create(username='test')

    self.assertEquals(user.modified, dt)
    self.assertEquals(user.timestamp, dt)
```

This is the best way to mock timezone.now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me with Django 2.1.5 and python 3.6.7

Comment: @chrisbu Note that fields with `auto_add_now` will not be overridden, as `auto_add_now` is a database-level instruction and not a python instruction. Django developers decided not to change this odd behavior. Reference: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16583

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs Seems a lot like Python to me: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2abf417c815c20f41c0868d6f66520b32347106e/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L450

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are patching timezone in the [wrong place.](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch)

Assuming your `User` model lives in `myapp\models.py` and you want to test `save()` in that file. The problem is that when you `from django.utils import timezone` at the top, it imports it from `django.utils`. In your test you are patching `timezone` locally, and it has no effect on your test, since module `myapp\models.py` already has a reference to the real `timezone` and it looks like our patching had no effect.

Try patching `timezone` from `myapp\models.py`, something like:

```
import myapp.models.timezone

def test_created(self):
    with patch('myapp.models.timezone') as mock_timezone:
        dt = datetime(2010, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        mock_timezone.now.return_value = dt

        assert myapp.models.timezone.now() == dt

        user = User.objects.create(username='test')
        self.assertEquals(user.modified, dt)
        self.assertEquals(user.timestamp, dt)
```

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately importing `timezone` from my models doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: give it a try with example: you have to patch on a module level, not just object.

Comment: looks like the default value is set way before the test (and patching) runs. There is probably some serious django magic that happens before test is even running.

Comment: @Oleksiy The magic is the following:  `auto_add_now` is a database-level instruction and not a python instruction. Django developers decided not to change this odd behavior. Reference: code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16583